# How can I put pagenumber into longtable header?

Tags: page-numbering, longtable

I try to fill a multipage table using `longtable` environment. I need to put some data before table parts on every page. To do this I write

```
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\tabheader}\\
\hline
% here i write header description\cr\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\cr\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{9}{l}{\tabheader}\\
\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\cr\hline
\endhead
```

The macro `\tabheader` puts some data about table and it also should contain current page number.

As I understand, head in `longtable` creates only once and later just copies (like `\copy0`). How can I do such changed header? I can't put it into page headers because the beginning of table have some text before table header.

Comment: I think, there's no other solution except page headers.

Comment: you can use supertab or there are some hints in the answer to a duplicate question, link to be added...